# Actual definition of cardiac output

Tags: human-physiology, definitions

Is cardiac output the amount of blood pumped by both ventricles in 1 minute or only by the left ventricle in 1 minute?

Answer (score 3):

Cardiac output is the amount of blood pumped **only** by the left ventricle, per minute.

Comment: Cardiac output (CO) has also been defined as the amount of blood pumped out by each ventricle in one minute. I've seen it both ways. Maybe a source would be good.